# tsql Utilizar PIVOT para trasponer filas con texto en columnas

Tags: tsql, pivot

Estoy intentando con la función PIVOT como indico a continuación. utilizo SQL Management 2012.  También he probado con XML y SQL Dinámico indicado en el siguiente post:

[Múltiples opciones para transponer filas en columnas](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/multiples-opciones-para-transponer-filas-en-columnas/)

Aunque los resultados han sido los mismos. Me devuelve Valor Null en las filas.

A. Creación del set de datos en una tabla temporal (Idem a la de producción):

```
USE tempdb
GO
CREATE TABLE #TMP 
(CODE VARCHAR(15), DESCRIPCIO VARCHAR(30), IDPARENT INT, ATRIBUTO VARCHAR(25), DES_CORTA VARCHAR(30) )
GO
INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES 
('PPU00001','Panel 1','10',' FAMILIA','Paneles Termicos Frigolit'),
('PPU00002','Panel 2','10',' FAMILIA','Paneles Termicos Frigolit'),
('PPU00001','Panel 1','52',' NUCLEO','PUR'),
('PPU00002','Panel 2','52',' NUCLEO','PUR'),
('PPU00001','Panel 1','55',' ESPESOR NUCLEO','Espesor 30 mm'),
('PPU00002','Panel 2','55',' ESPESOR NUCLEO','1: 4'),
('PPU00001','Panel 1','59',' ENCASTRE','Ensamble Engrafado'),
('PPU00002','Panel 2','59',' ENCASTRE','Ensamble Engrafado'),
('PPU00002','Panel 2','63',' REVESTIMIENTO EXTERIO','Bco. Dagrad'),
('PPU00001','Panel 1','66',' REV. ESPESOR(EXT.)','con 0.5 mm'),
('PPU00002','Panel 2','66',' REV. ESPESOR(EXT.)','0'),
('PPU00001','Panel 1','72',' REVESTIMIENTO INTERIOR','Bco. Nieve'),
('PPU00002','Panel 2','72',' REVESTIMIENTO INTERIOR','Bco. Nieve'),
('PPU00001','Panel 1','75',' REV. ESPESOR(INT.)','0.4 mm'),
('PPU00002','Panel 2','75',' REV. ESPESOR(INT.)','0'),
('PPU00001','Panel 1','78',' ANCHO','1010 mm'),
('PPU00002','Panel 2','78',' ANCHO','1010 mm'),
('PPU00002','Panel 2','83',' LARGO','250'),
('PPU00001','Panel 1','83',' LARGO','3000 mm')
GO
```

B. Uso de la consulta con la función PIVOT:

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT CODE, ATRIBUTO, DES_CORTA FROM #TMP
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(MAX([DES_CORTA])
    FOR [ATRIBUTO] In([ANCHO],[ENCASTRE],[ESPESOR NUCLEO],[FAMILIA],[LARGO],[NUCLEO],[REV. ESPESOR(EXT.)],
[REV. ESPESOR(INT.)],[REVESTIMIENTO EXTERIO],[REVESTIMIENTO INTERIOR])
) AS PVTTABLE
```

C. Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

D. Resultado Esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aguado comentarios.
Desde ya, muchas gracias.
Marcelo.

Comment: D. Resultado Esperado:

Comment: Tienes un error tipográfico, cuando insertas los valores, los atributos tienen un espacio delante, por eso no te toma el pivot. Puedes también quitar ese espacio mediante `LTRIM(ATRIBUTO) AS ATRIBUTO`

Comment: Patricio, buenos días y muchas gracias. Me hiciste visualizar un error que lo traía de arrastre. Ya que la fuente de datos original proviene de una Vista de SQL donde ahí el campo ATRIBUTO tenía el argumento: LTRIM(SUBSTRING(PADRE.DESCRIP, CHARINDEX(' ', PADRE.DESCRIP),LEN(PADRE.DESCRIP))) ATRIBUTO.  Claro que ahora con el agregado LTRIM que sugeriste.  Excelente aporte. Muchas gracias!